Unable to create migrations in ASP.NET MVC
I'm trying to create a simple database in ASP.NET MVC using DbContext and DbSets. The project uses Entity Framework, so I tried running
Enable-Migrations (yes, I know it's automatically set to true, or so I've been told). I then tried to run Add-Migration Initial and I always get the same exception thrown:

Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

There is a huge message above it and if needed I'll provide it.
I tried following the link the console suggested and enabled
<loadFromRemoteSources enabled='true'/>

created a new project to see if maybe the issue was in my code. Still the same issues. I checked for the latest versions and its all up to date
the error message:
PM> Enable-Migrations
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515) ---> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Design.Executor..ctor(String assemblyFile, IDictionary`2 anonymousArguments)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyString, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.AppDomain.CreateInstance(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
at System.Data.Entity.Tools.AppDomainExecutor..ctor(String assembly, String dataDirectory, String configurationFile, String rootNamespace, String language)
at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.ProjectCommandBase.CreateExecutor()
at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Commands.MigrationsEnableCommand.Execute()
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
at System.Data.Entity.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Please, provide the error message in your question

i have edited the question with the error message

the problem you're having is with your dotnet framework, check if your computer has the framework necessary, or consider downgrading your ef package to the framework supported by your computer and the project.

tried going from 4.8 to 4.7.2 the issue is still there. Im starting to wonder if the issue could be caused by something else. Some time ago i tried installing SQLExpress from Microsoft and i had 4 failed installations. Do you think they could interfere with my issues here?

I tried downgrading the EntityFramework as well down to 6.0.0 and still no fixes

I had similar issues once and all I did was update Visual Studio, mine worked fine but my colleague still had the issue after updating but right now i can't seem to remember what the fix was.
In the meantime make sure all your packages are on the same version and also install.NetSDK for your targeted framework.
Then try adding a migration using terminal instead of package manager console
`dotnet add migration 

The answer to my problem is really complicated to explain in a comment ill link a video which my professor found and followed step by step to fix my issue. Firstly noticed also that only AMD processors had this issue and its confusing why. Secondly i tried installing a MICROSOFT SQL SERVER, but had many failed installations..(Next comment). But everytime when i want to create a new project and use mvc framework i have change the connection string in the web config to a new connection string which was created from the video. here is the link:
https://youtu.be/MsxC3U6YFgM?si=dUAWg-xj8tciF-5O

I tried to install sql server express and had many failed installations i deleted them all first before the video and that you can do in program remove and find sql 2022 in my case click remove then remove all instances (User interface can be confusing but find the name of the installation and click remove). Then and only then you  can follow the instructions in the video. After finishing the instructions when you create a new MVC project go to the web config and find the connection string which should be something like (localdatabase)namename. Go to server explorer and click add a connecti...

click add a connection there if you followed the steps correctly will be a new connection that you can use copy the (localdatabse)MyProject or whatever your name is put it in the web config and it works. Saddly you have to do this all the time unless AMD fix this or Microsoft.
ps if it helps someone glad if not sad
